# Is there is any way to pass multiple values for a single key in the API URL

Tags: api, rest, postman

I am testing an API which is returning data for a single value passed query expression ex :- https://xyz/abc/latest/result?q=PersonId=11111111

but when I pass another personID ex :- https://xyz/abc/latest/result?q=PersonId=11111111&q=PersonId=2222222

it is still returning the data for the personID=11111111.

Can anyone suggest any idea to me - In fetching the data for multiple persons in one shot?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the API implementation, but I would suggest you to try with comma separated values on the desired parameter.
I.e: https://xyz/abc/latest/result?q=PersonId=11111111,2222222

Comment: thank you @Viizgar  for your time , already tried that but didn't work . It will be very helpful if you can provide me any link where I can take reference on how to check the particular implementation of parameter dealing